# could not launch Appium Inspector,could not start a new session

Tags: ios, appium

```
info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone 4s (DF6FC842-2BC2-4E50-B4C2-21B0DB2EEDEA)","platformVersion":"7.1"}
info: [debug] fixDevice is on

info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 4s (DF6FC842-2BC2-4E50-B4C2-21B0DB2EEDEA) (7.1 Simulator)'
info: [debug] Cleaning up appium session
error: Could not find a device to launch. You requested 'iPhone 4s (DF6FC842-2BC2-4E50-B4C2-21B0DB2EEDEA) (7.1 Simulator)', but the available devices were: ["iPhone 4s (7.1 Simulator) [45947AC6-A891-4B82-964A-757F73C952C1]","iPhone 4s (8.1 Simulator) [DF6FC842-2BC2-4E50-B4C2-21B0DB2EEDEA]","iPhone 5 (7.1 Simulator) [30810E10-6B35-468B-AE92-D6FBA6F43E17]","iPhone 5 (8.1 Simulator) [E1486B80-A4BF-45E2-9DA8-74EC32C2E012]","iPhone 5s (7.1 Simulator) [B3B1B343-5E89-4524-99FF-103F243FDAD0]","iPhone 5s (8.1 Simulator) [7B10F468-8F0E-4133-BB2D-8CFE003C8971]","iPhone 6 (8.1 Simulator) [C5876900-7406-4272-95FF-71688E26378D]","iPhone 6 Plus (8.1 Simulator) [E834C92E-7FE4-418F-B9E3-CDEEE2A9B4BC]"]
```

Comment: Check this https://discuss.appium.io/t/appium-1-3-1-inspector-doesnt-support-ios-8/1287/3

Answer (score 3):

there is another solution too which I found in Appium Github's forum and it helped not only me. Delete the long string part of Simulator name, for example, in your case change iPhone 4s (DF6FC842-2BC2-4E50-B4C2-21B0DB2EEDEA) to iPhone 4s. Hope this helps too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after suffering 5-6 days, I found out that I have not downloaded that simulator in xcode. You request iPhone 4s working on iOS 7.1, but you don't have it downloaded (I guess). or try to download it, or try to request an available simulator, like iPhone 5 working on 7.1. 
Hope this helps =)